# wso2 app manager source code modification

Tags: build, wso2

[build wso2 apim 1.10.0 from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181440/build-wso2-apim-1-10-0-from-source#new-answer)

can anyone explain the same(above link) for wso2 app manager ?? I need to use carbon-appmgt and product-appmgt??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're correct.

You have to build `carbon-appmgt` and `product-appmgt`.